# How does FB Rate Limit work for App Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on an app which implements the traditional email / password method along with Facebook login. I am working on a search autocomplete feature so when a user types in, for example, "hou" it will return cities matching that term like "Houston, Texas".

Since not all users will be logged in with Facebook I'll be using the App Access Token to call Facebooks API. This is the endpoint I am getting my data from:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=["city"]&country_code=US&q=hou&access_token=
```

My question is how does the Rate Limit work on a per user basis if I am using my App Access Token? Since the App Access Token identifies the app how does Facebook manage the 200 calls / hour per user rate?

I am concerned with getting rate limited as it would break my app search feature.